# How to add items to pyqt4 combobox when GUI already displayed?

Tags: python-2.7, combobox, pyqt4

i'm running a python gui thet build with QT, and i want it to display the all COM ports thet connect to PC in combobox.
I have recognized the ports and i put them  to a list but i cant make the gui display any list or items.

here is my code...

class GUI():

```
 def GUI(self):
    self.app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    self.ex = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ex.setupUi(win)
    setup.SetCOmboBoxes()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(self.app.exec_())



  def SetCOmboBoxes(self):
    gui.ex.BaudRateCombobox.addItems(["sss","FFF","ddd"])
    gui.ex.BaudRateCombobox.update()
    print "here"
```

the GUI is running whel but the combobox stays empty

Comment: Try: `QtGui.qApp.processEvents()`.

Comment: where do i think i should place it?

Comment: @A_V_A please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @ekhumoro I do not think it is necessary to use processEvents (in general the use of that function implies a bad design), I think the problem is caused by a part of the code that the OP does not show us.

Comment: @eyllanesc It doesn't imply any such thing. Qt has included it since version 2, and it is there for perfectly good reasons. Any API can be used in a bad way - there's nothing special about `processEvents`.

Comment: @ekhumoro I do not say that it is bad but it is often used badly because processevents sounds like magic (it seems to say if the GUI is not updated then it uses processevents), and I have seen in many cases that it only hides the real problem and that after some time the problem explodes :-)

Comment: @ekhumoro So I prefer to understand the problem before proposing a response that can solve the problem but in the long term it is not because it is not appropriate. For example a bad use is when you want to do 3 tasks that modify the GUI, one after 1 second of the other, and obviously call processevents with a sleep function because the view is updated but other tasks that are not necessarily visual are seen affected since only the problem was solved superficially.

Comment: @ekhumoro Going to the problem, the qcombobox should be updated without problems. So I suspect that even if your suggestion helps to update the view the cause of the underlying problem would persist.

Comment: @eyllanesc Note that I simply said ***try*** it. I think you are making a mountain out of a molehill, here. The Qt docs for `processEvents` suggest that "you can call this function occasionally when your program is busy performing a long operation". So if the OP tries it, and it works, I think that might help clarify their question (which is what the comments are for).

Comment: i got it! i should run it from the same thread! theanks!